# If I bind one control to the other, and one of the control dies, what happens to the binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

for example, let's take a programmatic binding:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("MyProperty");
binding.Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
binding.Source = myWindow.myObject

myButton.SetBinding(Button.VisibilityProperty, binding);
```

What happens if myWindow dies and gets garbage collected... am I responsible for freeing up the binding as well, or does it know how to do that itself?

Comment: I don't think that the other control can get GC'd as there is still a reference to it via the binding.

Comment: Please don't use things like "C#:" in your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: kay, i'll stop doing that... good point

Comment: Depends.. what's the life expectancy of the window?

Comment: not very long and this is for many windows that get created and destroyed

Answer (score 2):

This is not true for Bindings, you'll have no memory leak even if you use `Source` for the `Binding`.

To verify this

- Create a `StackPanel`, a `TextBox` (tb1) and two `Buttons` in Xaml
- In code behind you create a new `TextBox` (tb2)
- Set a `Binding` on tb1 with `Source` set to tb2
- Create a `WeakReference` on tb2 (which shouldn't be GC'd if we have a leak)
- Add tb2 to the `StackPanel`
- Run the program and verify that the binding works
- Click Remove
- Click Is Alive?

It returns false, the source `TextBox` (tb2) has been garbage collected so we have no memory leak

**Edit:** You can also move the creation of the first `TextBox` from Xaml to code behind and use two `WeakReferences` (one for each `TextBox`) and verify that both textBoxes get GC'd properly and you'll see that this is true.

*Xaml*

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanel">
    <TextBox Name="textBox"/>
    <Button Name="removeButton" Content="Remove" Click="removeButton_Click"/>
    <Button Name="isAliveButton" Content="Is Alive?" Click="isAliveButton_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

*Code Behind*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBox toBeGCdTextBox = new TextBox();
        stackPanel.Children.Add(toBeGCdTextBox);
        Binding textBinding = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
            Source = toBeGCdTextBox
        };
        textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textBinding);
        _weak = new WeakReference(toBeGCdTextBox);
    }
    private WeakReference _weak;
    private void isAliveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        MessageBox.Show(_weak.IsAlive.ToString());
    }

    private void removeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_weak.Target == stackPanel.Children[3]);
        stackPanel.Children.Remove(stackPanel.Children[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting... although you did mention it returns some kind of warning in the background. i intend to create and destroy alot of these windows, so i'm not sure if binding is best practice here. (and yes, i need to bind between properties on main window and property on windows that are opened and closed many times), perhaps i'll do some kind of event firing instead... i'm not sure if this is best practice even if there's no memory issues

Comment: I removed that comment because it wasn't true. I just tried it and you don't get any warnings in the Output window when the source sees to exist. I'm not sure of the reason for this though as they appear if you use an invalid `RelativeSource` with FindAncestor, invalid property on the `DataContext` etc. It'll look something like this: **System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference...**

Comment: so the plot thickens... i need my main window's ui to react to properties changed in child windows... do you think binding is the way to go here or perhaps some other type of communication? you seemed to prove that binding doesn't have alot of disadvantages so i'm a bit mixed up

Comment: I usually go for bindings to the ViewModels so I'm not sure. I have never thought about the possibilty of this. But so long as you set new bindings between your windows (when one die there isn't anything to bind to anyway) it should work

Comment: +1 for binding multiple windows to a common viewmodel. Define the child window bindings in the child windows (preferably in XAML, to ensure you don't introduce anything funky in code) and let WPF clean up automatically when the child window is collected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it will *not* be garbage collected, as

> The object is alive until the garbage collector finds out that the
>   object is no longer reachable from a strong root reference via a path
>   of strong references

from here [Managing object lifetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163316.aspx)

you still have a pointer `binding.**Source**` to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN :

> In C# garbage collection is handled by the comman language runtime
>   (CLR) which is similar the Java's JVM. Garbage collecter periodically
>   checks the memory heap for any ***unreferenced*** objects, and
>   releases the resources held by these objects.

Therefore, in your example myWindow object cannot be garbage collected since there is a reference from binding object to myWindow.